# how to add number with array join() method in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting

Question About Join method in python,

I have data

```
data = ['my', 'name', 'is']
```

I print like that

```
str1 = '\n'.join(str(e) for e in data)
print(str1)
```

output

```
my
name
is
```

how to add number like?

```
1 my
2 name
3 is
```

Comment: edited sorry

before z and a is my local variable

Comment: `print('\n'.join('%d %s' % t for t in enumerate(data, 1)))`

Comment: BTW, Python has several different array-like data structures: tuple, list, and [array.array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html). And then there are Numpy arrays.  So to avoid confusion it's a good idea to use the correct names. However, `.join` is _not_ a list method, it's a string method which accepts an iterable of strings as its argument.

Comment: yap i need data as string, that why i use str `str1 = '\n'.join(**str(e)** for e in data`

Comment: But in your example, the items in `data` are already strings, so doing `str(e)` is pointless. If `data = ['my', 'name', 'is']` then `str1 = '\n'.join(str(e) for e in data)` is just an inefficient way of doing `str1 = '\n'.join(data)`.

Comment: Sorry for that, in case i used join() for data from sql database. I am just copy and paste my code to question that why i am included my local variable z and a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `enumerate`:

```
print('\n'.join(str(i) + ' ' + j for i, j in enumerate(data, 1)))

1 my
2 name
3 is
```